# Grunt required options for specific task

Tags: gruntjs

I'd like to fail a grunt task before executing if a certain cli option is not present. At present I have the following:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    mytask: {
      default: {
        launch_url: (grunt.option("url") || grunt.fail.warn("Set url with --url.")),
      },
      options: {}...
```

There must be a cleaner way to do this- i just want the cli to require a url at runtime rather than raising some unintelligble error later.

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post : https://jordankasper.com/bending-grunt-to-your-will-with-custom-tasks-part-2/](https://jordankasper.com/bending-grunt-to-your-will-with-custom-tasks-part-2/) shows how to check the process.os for operating system and run different tasks depending on which one the user has. You could do a similar thing with by testing with `process.argv` and then failing if it doesn't meet matching criteria for the argument with a `grunt.fail.fatal`.

Comment: ok. i was hoping for something similar to the requireConfig property for grunt.option. thanks! do you see a problem with the way I did it using control flow?

Comment: nothing wrong with it, .option("url") does the same thing as process.argv. To do it outside the grunt config, just put a check before the init to exit if the arg isn't present if(!process.argv.indexOf("url")) { throw new Error("set url with --url"); } or the like.